# I could not acquire the image from the API of spotify

Tags: javascript, json, spotify

I'm trying to create a site in which, through the Spotify Web API, I display the information of a certain element (Artist, Track, Album, etc ...). In the background of the object of the answer, however, I would like to set the image that is provided directly by Spotify but, after several attempts, I still can not.
This is my function.

```
function ricercaArtista(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var artist =document.getElementById("artista").value;
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            var result = '';
            for(var i = 0; i < response.artists.items.length; i++){
                console.log(response.artists.items[i]);             
                result +='<div class="panel panel-primary" style="background:url('+
                response.artists.items[i].images[1].url+');"><div class="panel-body">' + 
                'name : ' + response.artists.items[i].name + '<br/>' +                  
                'popularity : ' + response.artists.items[i].popularity + '<br/>' + 
                'type : ' + response.artists.items[i].type + '</div></div>';
            }   
           alert
            document.getElementById("artists").innerHTML = result;
            }   
        };
        xhr.open('GET', "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q="+artist+"&type=artist&market=IT&limit=10&offset=5", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer BQAnHZ_1kZFp_6rNx7jWXz-wfK9KTp2gTmuviXisgsJy8IAjnF_Hbo701Y5UMu7viFb0vaKG6wBAcLQMhfNUBjzGZpt1M3UaWGEKWDVmziEh-s6ECFNeVFCifdD3C38w3q_jGdnovDUlek2f463hnyPUlpoC4xb2uA');
        xhr.send();
    }
```

the error of the Console of Chrome is:
`Index.html:29 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange`

Comment: The error means that `response.artists.items[i].images[1]` is `undefined`. Why `[1]`?  Do you know that there will be at least two images? (JavaScript arrays start at 0, not 1.)

Comment: yes, in the json response there are 3 images

Comment: Well apparently not, or else you wouldn't be getting that error. You can add an explicit test to make sure that there are images for each of the "items" you get before attempting to access the "url" property.

Answer (score 0):

@Pointy is right, some the records has an empty array on Image path. 
Look at the fetch below it returns different records to search Bob marley.
you can see the result in console.
in this case you need to check image path if it's empty Do something.

```
fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=bob marley&type=artist&market=IT&limit=10&offset=5")
.then(res=> res.json())
.then(data=> console.log(data.artists.items))
.catch(err=> console.log(err));
```